# Node.contains() returns incorrect value on PhantomJS, but not on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, phantomjs

I'm trying to write a test for a particular function that takes selected text and highlights it by giving it a particular css class.  The function works just fine, and the test passes when run via Chrome, but when running the test using PhantomJS, it fails.  It appears that `Node.contains()` is returning the incorrect value in PhantomJS, which is why the test is failing.  Here is the relevant code:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var parent = document.getElementById('text-container-items');
console.log(parent);
console.log(range.startContainer);
console.log(range.endContainer);
console.log(parent.contains(range.startContainer));
console.log(parent.contains(range.endContainer));
if (!parent.contains(range.startContainer) || !parent.contains(range.endContainer)) {
    console.log('Returned early');
    return;
}
```

Here are the results of each of the `console.log` statements (when running tests using PhantomJS):

*console.log(parent)*

```
<div class="text-container-items" id="text-container-items" data-reactid=".38.1">
    <div class="textBlock" data-reactid=".38.1.$0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="textBlock" data-reactid=".38.1.$1">
        consectetur adipiscing elit
    </div>
    <div class="textBlock" data-reactid=".38.1.$2">
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    </div>
</div>
```

*console.log(range.startContainer)*

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

*console.log(range.endContainer)*

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

*console.log(parent.contains(range.startContainer))*

```
false
```

*console.log(parent.contains(range.endContainer))*

```
false
```

These `console.log` statements are the same in Chrome, except the last two, which both print `true`.

So... what gives?  Does `Node.contains()` just not work in PhantomJS?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use? Have you tried v2.0.0?

Comment: I thought we were on 2.0.0 but I never bothered to check before posting this.  Turns out we're on 1.9.8.  I'll upgrade and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I updated to 2.0.0 and it is still failing :/

Comment: @ArtjomB. Apparently my Karma test runner was still using 1.9.8 when I had 2.0.0 installed.  I fixed that and the issue no longer occurs.  If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.  Thanks!